# EF Core fromsql select multiple value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to select Id from Technician table and Name from AspNetUsers table. Sql command works in sql server but in core project query return `IQueryable<Technician>` but Technician table doesn't have a Name column. How can I fix it?

```
public IQueryable<Technician> GetTechnician()
{
    var x = context.Technician .FromSql(@"
    select t.id,r.Name from technician t
    inner join AspNetUsers r on t.user_id = r.Id
   ");
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either create a class that inherits from `Technician` and Have a Name Property:

```
public class NamedTechnician: Technician
{
     public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

or you can just use anonymous return type:

```
context.Technician.Select(x=> new {Id = x.Id, Name = x.AspNetUser.Name, ....});
```

Comment: I got this error when I generate different class:

Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[Project.Entity.Technician]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Project.Entity.NamedTechnician]'.


My Code like this:
public IQueryable<NamedTechnician> GetTechnician()
    {
            var x =  context.Technician.FromSql(@".....");   
        return (IQueryable<NamedTechnician>)x;
        }

Comment: do it like this: `context.Technician.Select(x=> new NamedTechnician{Id = x.Id, Name = x.AspNetUser.Name, ....});`